# JSON with spaces in Hashmap - From api

Tags: java, android, arrays

I get a list of names etc back form an API.

My app crashes with the exception if there are spaces in the JSONArray's object

this is the Array from a HashMap:

```
{id="a5b140c9-9987-4e6d-a883-a18c00726883", children=[{id=fe103303-fd5e-4cd6-81a0-a18c00733737, children=[], parentid=a5b140c9-9987-4e6d-a883-a18c00726883, name=Contains Spaces}], parentid=, name=Kiosk}
```

then I iterate trough its children:

```
JSONArray child = new JSONArray(json.get("children").toString());                               
for ( int i=0; i<child.length();i++ ) {

}
```

This part gives an exception because of the space in here:

```
JSONArray child = new JSONArray(json.get("children").toString())
name=Contains Spaces
```

d

```
03-26 10:31:56.409: W/System.err(4793): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-26 10:31:56.417: W/System.err(4793):     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
03-26 10:31:56.417: W/System.err(4793):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
03-26 10:31:56.417: W/System.err(4793):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
03-26 10:31:56.417: W/System.err(4793):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
03-26 10:31:56.417: W/System.err(4793):     at com.example.tvrplayer.ChannelsDialogPreference$1$1.run(ChannelsDialogPreference.java:158)
```

Comment: current string is not an valid json String

Comment: Your JSON is not correct. check here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: first of all this is not a valid json .. {"id":"a5b140c9-9987-4e6d-a883-a18c00726883",... it should be like that pls refer json format

Comment: Yes I know, thats why I said "this is the Array from a HashMap". Thats what I have, I need to work with it.

Comment: Go to [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) Paste your string here and click on validate.

Comment: This worked, JSONArray child = new JSONArray(json.get("children").toString().replace("=",":"));

Answer (score 1):

Is the first piece of code in your message JSON? I recall all key and string values have to be included in "". And : instead of = Should be something like:

```
{"id":"a5b140c9-9987-4e6d-a883-a18c00726883", "children":[{"id":"fe103303-fd5e-4cd6-81a0-a18c00733737", "children":[], "parentid":"a5b140c9-9987-4e6d-a883-a18c00726883", "name":"Contains Spaces"}], "parentid":"", "name":"Kiosk"}
```

see: [JSON Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)

If it is javascript, you still should write string values with "" (all, not just those with spaces).